# Options for Debugging Akka applications? - Activator or/and something else ?

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe-activator, typesafe-console

Someone told me that I should use the TypeSafe console to debug issues in my Akka app. Search for the console takes me [this page](https://typesafe.com/blog/typesafe_console_-_now_free_for_developers). However, the link directs me to [Typesafe Activator](http://typesafe.com/activator). I'm assuming Activator replaced the console.

However, I couldn't find any documentation that tells me how I can trace a running Akka system and debug it. Any pointers about how what my options would be appreciated.  Also, how can I use Activator to debug my Akka app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/akka-user/monitor/akka-user/lZ3UjPoy1go/X0VYwjBe8ScJ) on the akka mailing list recenty.

Regarding activator see this [video](http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted).

And there's is also [New Relic](http://typesafe.com/blog/webinar-monitoring-your-play-apps-with-new-relic-).

Answer (score 5):

I can also mention [Kamon.io](http://kamon.io/) and [akka-tracing](https://github.com/levkhomich/akka-tracing) projects. Both of them can serve as debug tools (first one is more metrics-oriented and second one is a dedicated tracing tool).

Full disclosure: I'm the maintainer of akka-tracing who faced similar problems =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Activator will replace the Console soon, which is now only in maintenance.
In Activator you can use the Inspect feature to get some insight into your app.

Other than that if you say "debug" - normal debugging (as in just using an IDE) also works, but yes - in message driven apps is a bit harder to apply.